# Tool to delete all data from a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, arctoolbox, update

I am looking for a tool that deletes the data in the shapefile, and then copy and pastes all the features from a layer into the blank layer.

We get updates to our layer from a separate organization, but our data fields are slightly different and we have a few of our own fields. The fields that are the same have the same field name so they paste properly when you paste a layer in editor.  I would also like to eventually make this run as a timed script, so it needs to be a python friendly method. I would prefer to keep the layer the way I have it, rather than just append our own data on the end of the updated data.

Comment: Try looking into the Delete Features and Append tools.

Comment: Can you expand more on the delete part (e.g. what, when, why...etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I am understanding the workflow correctly but like Beck said I think this is does the trick. Foo is the original shapefile you are deleting all the features from, Bar is the layer you are copying features from.

```
import arcpy

# Data
foo = r'C:\Path\to\layer\that\will\be\blank.shp'
bar = r'C:\Path\to\layer\that\gets\copied.shp'

# Delete Features
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(foo)

# Append
arcpy.Append_management(bar, foo, "NO_TEST", "", "")
```

Comment: This is exactly the tool I needed. To everyone else who goes to try it, I would like to point out the importance of using "NO_TEST" if the data is not the same. Thanks Chris!